# ionViewCanLeave does not trigger when leaving a page, any other ways to do this? Ionic 2 Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I am switching from the nav root the ionViewCanLeave triggers, but when I am switching between pages it does not. Is there a different method or any other way to do this?

I need to set an alert for validation and not allow them to leave the page until it is filled out correctly.

```
ionViewCanLeave() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.allTimeEntries.length; i++) {
        if (this.allTimeEntries[i].hours > 0 && this.allTimeEntries[i].paycode != '' && this.allTimeEntries[i].description != '') {
            this.IsValid = true;
        } else if (this.allTimeEntries[i].hours == 0 || this.allTimeEntries[i].paycode == '' || this.allTimeEntries[i].description == '') {
            this.IsValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!this.IsValid) {
        let alertPopup = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Invalid Hours',
            message: 'Hours, Pay Code, & Description are required.',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Ok',
                handler: () => {
                }
            },
            {
            }]
        });
        alertPopup.present();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also work the same way

```
  ionViewWillLeave() { 
     }
```

or you can check ionic navController hooks